# Java - Improving Consumer Producer with MultiThreading using ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

i am trying to solve consumer-producer problem with multi-Threading by using ConcurrentHashMap and newFixedThreadPool.

my goal is to make diffrerent threads to put and remove from hashmap simultaneously and Ensure that map size will not be bigger than MAXQUEUE,
unique key to each element.

the program below isn't behave as i descirbed, it's fill the map until the size is 20 and then it removes 20 and so on.

I need some help to make it bahave as the description, 
also i will be glad to get suggestion to improve the code.

this is my Producer Class:

```
public class Producer extends Thread
{
static final int MAXQUEUE = 20;
private ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, String>();
private AtomicLong m_Key = new AtomicLong(0);

public void run() 
{
    try 
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            putMessage();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
    }
}

private void putMessage() throws InterruptedException 
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        while (myMap.size() == MAXQUEUE) 
        {
            wait();
        }
        myMap.put(this.m_Key.incrementAndGet(), "Hello");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " put message; key " + this.m_Key);
        notify();
        //Later, when the necessary event happens, the thread that is running it calls notify() from a block synchronized on the same object.
    }
}

// Called by Consumer    
public void removeElementFromMap() throws InterruptedException
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        notify();
        while (myMap.size() == 0)
        {
            wait();
        }

        for (Iterator<Entry<Long, String>> iter = this.myMap.entrySet().iterator() ; iter.hasNext() ; ) 
        {
            Map.Entry<Long, String> entry = iter.next();   
            System.out.println("Removed element with key " + entry.getKey() );
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Consumer Class:

```
public class Consumer extends Thread
{
Producer producer;


   public void Consumer(Producer p) 
{
    producer = p;
}

public void run() 
{
    try 
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            producer.removeElementFromMap();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Producer producer = new Producer();
    ExecutorService producersExecutors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    Consumer consumer = new Consumer(producer);
    ExecutorService consumersExecutors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        producersExecutors.execute(producer);
        consumersExecutors.execute(consumer);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: You could probably throw all of this away and use a simple [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#ArrayBlockingQueue%28int%29).

Comment: i most to use hashmap.   my question is how to make the trheads to wirk simultaniously, not wait until the map will rich size of 20 and only then to remove 20 elements and so on.

Comment: FYI, races can mean that you lose notifications - use `notifyAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blocking queues available in Java e.g. ArrayBlockingQueue.
But if you still want to use map and your own way of handling this then may be you can do it like below -

```
public class MapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataStore dataStore = new DataStore(100);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new Producer(dataStore));
            executorService.execute(new Consumer(dataStore));
        }
    }
}

class DataStore {

    private final int maxQueueSize;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private AtomicInteger queueSize = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private AtomicLong keyGenerator = new AtomicLong(0);
    private Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();

    public DataStore(int maxQueueSize) {
        this.maxQueueSize = maxQueueSize;
    }

    public void putMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        while (queueSize.get() == maxQueueSize) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (queueSize.get() < maxQueueSize) {
                map.put(keyGenerator.incrementAndGet(), "Hello");
                queueSize.incrementAndGet();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " put message; key " + keyGenerator.get() + ", queue size: " + queueSize.get());
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void removeMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        while (queueSize.get() == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (queueSize.get() > 0) {
                Iterator<Long> keyIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
                if (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Long key = keyIterator.next();
                    map.remove(key);
                    queueSize.decrementAndGet();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " removed message; key: " + key + ", queue size: " + queueSize.get());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {

    private DataStore dataStore;

    public Producer(DataStore dataStore) {
        this.dataStore = dataStore;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                dataStore.putMessage();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private DataStore dataStore;

    public Consumer(DataStore dataStore) {
        this.dataStore = dataStore;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                dataStore.removeMessage();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```